# Docker-based PAAS supporting multiple containers

Tags: docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, paas

Are there any docker hosts who natively support multiple containers (e.g. can separate node.js and nginx into their own containers) and who also take a PAAS approach to hosting?

I don't want to define PAAS too narrowly - obviously the Heroku model inspires. AWS Elastic Beanstalk supports docker and advanced PAAS capabilities such as automatic email notifications, log rotation, etc. But they only support one container per instance today.

Comment: Something like https://www.orchardup.com/?

Comment: Seems they're closing it down in October: https://www.orchardup.com/blog/orchard-is-joining-docker. It was a little too "bare bones" for what I'm looking for, although Fig is great.

Comment: https://www.tutum.co/

Answer (score 1):

Two options that I can think of are tutum.com (fully managed infrastructure) and dockerize.it (docker on any infrastructure —aws, digital ocean, your own servers or any shared hosting where you can install a docker server).

(disclosure: I am part of dockerize.it)